Compiled i686-linux-gnu glibc on x86_64 not working
On my x86_64 machine, when I configure the glibc (cloned from this) with (I want to build a 32bit sysroot),
../configure --prefix=/sysroot-coulson --host=i686-linux-gnu --build=i686-linux-gnu\
    CFLAGS=" -fstrict-aliasing -O2 -g -mno-tls-direct-seg-refs" \
    CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" \
    CFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686" \
    CXXFLAGS="-O2 -march=i686"

I successfully build and installed the sysroot, but when I use gcc to compile hello.c using this sysroot by the command
gcc \
  -L "/sysroot-coulson/lib" \
  -I "/sysroot-coulson/include" \
  -g \
  -m32 \
  --sysroot /sysroot-coulson \
  -Wl,--rpath="/sysroot-coulson/lib -m32" \
  -std=c11 \
  -o hello.out \
  -v \
  hello.c \
;

the linker always complains
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /sysroot-coulson/lib/libc.so.6 inside /sysroot-coulson
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /sysroot-coulson/lib/libc_nonshared.a inside /sysroot-coulson
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /sysroot-coulson/lib/ld-linux.so.2 inside /sysroot-coulson

But actually all of these files exists with the right permission, I also verified the file format
/sysroot-coulson/lib/libc.so.6: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /sysroot-coulson/lib/ld-linux.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=abe0474c6ebaeb5553eeec39959f08b704e3e182, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped

Which is exactly the format of the lib32/libc.so.6  installed by apt and works well compiling stuff to 32bit

Maybe try updating the loader cache: ldconfig
